# free memory netbeans plugin

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-plugins

Is there any plugin for NetBeans to free memory manually?
NetBeans' core has this feature but it is not complete.

Comment: in middle of run catch the exception for not enough memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.omegat.org/en/omegat.html

Comment: I can't import this in netbeans but it is usable .

Answer (score 2):

You can't free memory whenever you want in a Java application! The only way to free memory in Java is to call "System.gc()", but this just [suggests](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc%28%29) the Java Virtual Machine to run the garbage collector (the JVM is free to do the gc or not).

If you're running out of memory while running NetBeans you may want to modify the [netbeans]/etc/netbeans.conf and modify the line that starts with "netbeans_default_options". For instance:

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-Xms384m -J-Xmx512m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=96m -J-Xverify:none"
```

Anyway remember that modifying the memory for NetBeans does not affect the applications you run with NetBeans, because those run in another Java Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 1):

You dont any plugin just click on the default memory bar in the toolbar

Answer (score 1):

this may be relevant and helpful...

Had a similar memory problem on my Linux Debian.

Here is how to fix it:

1. run a terminal
2. log in as root
3. type `crontab -e`
4. scroll to the bottom or the file and type `* * * * * sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

This magic line cleared all unused ram every minute.  It removed the unused memory NetBeans was producing (including any other memory-consuming programs).

This should work on most UNIX like OS's.

plz tell me if it works...